# Laravel: Deleting Eloquent aggregates

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm looking for a strategy for destroying Eloquent aggregates, e.g. models that "contain" other models.

In Ruby on Rails's ActiveRecord, there is a `dependent: :destroy`option that can be placed when defining relations, meaning that if e.g. an `order` is deleted, then the `order_lines` must go too.

Is there something similar in Laravel? Or any other alternatives besides manually cleaning up and wrapping it in a transaction?

Comment: Have you thought about setting ondelete properly for related tables in DB?

Comment: ondelete? Are you talking about database triggers? I don't want to put this kind of logic into the database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically deleting related rows in Laravel (Eloquent ORM)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Laravel schema builder, you should use foreign key and for foreign key add for example:

```
$table->foreign('entry_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('entries')
    ->onDelete('CASCADE');
```

You can of course do the same in for example phpMyAdmin.

When using such construction, if in this case record from `entries` will be deleted, automatically record from this table that have `entry_id` the same as `id` from `entries` that is being delete will be deleted.

It's not a trigger, because trigger are much more complex structure, it's just defining relation and telling what to do if related parent record will be deleted.

Comment: As much as this is a way of doing it, it's not the solution. I'm looking for a way to get Laravel/Eloquent to work. Not my SQL database.

Comment: @NielsB Maybe you want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm then but using `onDelete` is the best option I think without coding

Comment: I agree, but I prefer coding. Thanks for the link to the other question. I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.