# Deleting related models one-to-many in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is this even possible? 
In every tutorial that I read there is nothing about deleting, only selecting and inserting related models.

This is my problem:

I have three levels of nesting. I have classes Package, Level, Lesson and Phase, and their models are below. First one - packages:

```
class Package extends Eloquent  {

protected $table = 'packages';
public $timestamps = false;

public function levels(){
    return $this->hasMany('Level', 'package_id');
}
```

}

Levels:

```
class Level extends Eloquent  {

protected $table = 'levels';

public function lessons(){
    return $this->hasMany('Lesson', 'level_id');
}

public function package(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Package', 'package_id');
}
```

}

Lessons:

class Lesson extends Eloquent  {

```
protected $table = 'lessons';

public function phases(){
    return $this->hasMany('Phase', 'lesson_id');
}

public function level(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Level', 'level_id');
}
```

}

What I'm trying to do here is to when deleting one package i delete all levels related to it and also to delete all lessons related to those levels.

I have tried couple of options and they were all wrong, I just don't know how to do this without making a bunch of queries in foreach loop.
Please, give some advice I'm so desperate I'm thinking about tweet to Jeffrey Way and ask him for the solution :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can approach this in two ways:

1. Leverage the database to do the deleting for you. You'd add something like this to your migrations for the `lessons`, `levels` and `packages`, respectively:

   ```
    $table->foreign('level_id')->references('id')->on('levels')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('lesson_id')->references('id')->on('lessons')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('package_id')->references('id')->on('packages')->onDelete('cascade');
   ```
2. You can overwrite the `delete` method on each model to delete all of its relationships:

   ```
   class Lesson extends Eloquent {

       protected $table = 'lessons';

       public function phases(){
           return $this->hasMany('Phase', 'lesson_id');
       }

       public function level(){
           return $this->belongsTo('Level', 'level_id');
       }

       public function delete()    
       {
           DB::transaction(function() 
           {
               $this->level()->delete();
               $this->phases()->delete();
               parent::delete();
           });
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: One thing to take into consideration about the second approach: it might be wise to wrap the call to `delete()` in a transaction, to avoid having inconsistencies if any of the queries fail.

Comment: Definitely a good idea **@Bogdan**. Edited to include the transaction

Comment: Worth noting: 1st option won't work with `softDeletes` at all, and 2nd won't use `softDeletes` (it will run raw delete).

Comment: Thank you @edopaez I used your solution. First i had to dive into migrations a bit and thank you for that also because I know more now that before your post :) sorry I'm late with response btw

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `foreign keys` with `drop cascade` in your case. I haven't worked with Laravel's ORM yet, but there is a [section in documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#foreign-keys) that describes how to create foreign keys in migration.

Or you can try the technique suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm). The idea is to override the `delete` method and force the deletion of related objects.