# Laravel 5.1 Delete relationships

Tags: php, laravel, relationships

My models relationship is oneToMany eg: PatientToSample

Patient_Model:

```
class Patient_Model extends Model implements Jsonable{

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'patients';

    public function samples(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Sample_Model','code','patient_id');
}


}
```

Sample_Model :

```
class Sample_Model extends Model{

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'samples';

    public function patient(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Patient_Model','patient_id','code');
}

}
```

I think use the function delete Patient and Sample

```
public function delete(Request $request){
    $patient = Patient_Model::withTrashed()
        ->where("id",$request->get("id"))
        ->delete();

    return json_encode($patient);
}
```

But now only delete Patient....

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15019260/2772319

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically deleting related rows in Laravel (Eloquent ORM)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Answer (score 4):

This is one way to do it.

```
public function delete(Request $request){
    $patient = Patient_Model::withTrashed()
        ->find($request->get("id"));

    $patient->samples()->delete();
    $patient->delete();
    return json_encode($patient);
}
```

There is also a way to attach the relationship deletion to a delete event of the parent model, as discussed [here](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/using-model-events-to-delete-related-items).

Comment: This is not what OP is looking for. You are doing this inside a controller. OP wants the related rows to be deleted automatically without the need for the answer you gave.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but that is a simple modification to the exact code OP posted, and looks to me like he is trying to delete relationship when the parent model is deleted as mentioned in these lines: "I think use the function delete Patient and Sample".. " But now only delete Patient....".

Answer (score 2):

Did you set constraints in migration?
Just write into Sample table migration row:

```
$table->foreign('patient_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('patients')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

For more info: [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)