# delete record related through two field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have two models:
model 1
field id, field_a, field_b

model 2
id2, field_a, field_b

on $model1->delete() I would like to delete also $model2 where field_a and field_b are the same of $model1 (both of them)

Example

```
model1
1, 2, 5

model2
1, 2, 4
2, 3, 5
3, 2, 5 (to be deleted)
```

I don't know if this could be helpful
[Automatically deleting related rows in Laravel (Eloquent ORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a delete event on model 1 that deletes model 2 where the values match.

In `model 1` add the following...

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::deleted(function($model1) {
        Model2::where('field_1', $model1->field_1)->where('field_2', $model1->field_2)->delete()
    });
}
```

Now whenever you delete model 1, model 2 with matching attributes are also removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just find and delete the rows from model2 where the column values are similar.

```
Model2::where('field_a',$model1->field_a)->where('field_b',$model1->field_b)->delete();

$model1->delete();
```

Here, **Model2** is the class of the Second model.