# Retrieve soft deleted user posts in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

is there any way to retrieve posts that are related to a soft deleted user in laravel 5.4? Im thinking since the user is still in the database there should be a way.

Comment: Usually "soft deleting" is done by setting a Boolean Flag "Deleted" to true on that record. The Queries skip over the ones with "Deleted" for pure user side listings. But as you said, they are still in there for direct links or getting their name for existing posts. I have no experience with laravel 5.4, but there should be no technical reason for there being no way. Both an Override or a Default value could easily accomplish this. Would bet more on a override (performance reasons with DB queries).

Comment: Soft-deleting a user a) leaves the user in the database (go look) and b) does nothing to its relationships (unless you coded your own logic to do that). Have you *tried* to access these posts in any way? What code are you using?

Comment: yes but for some reason when i soft delete a user along with its post it fails everytime public function destroy($id)
    {
        $admins  = User::findOrFail($id);
        $admins  ->project()->delete();
       $admins->project()->delete();
          return redirect()->back();
    }     this is the destroy method im using and ive already set up  the relations and everything else

Comment: Yes, of course that fails. The user can't be found, because it was deleted. You don't want normal queries to return deleted records. You need to use `withTrashed` to access deleted items, or you could delete the relationships before the user. This is very clearly laid out in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#soft-deleting) in the "Querying Soft Deleted Models" section.

Answer (score 6):

When you soft delete a record, it gets `flagged` as deleted in the database, but the record is still there.

You can still retrieve it like this:

```
$users = App\User::withTrashed()->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't prefer to restore a deleted post and keep the own user deleted cause that's will return a broken relation.

but if you want to restore it and know the id of the deleted user you can restore like that:

```
Post::onlyTrashed()->where('user_id', $id)->restore();
```

Again, I **recommend** to not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

$onlySoftDeleted = Post::onlyTrashed()->get();

to get All deleted records

Answer (score -1):

This should work, I think.

```
Post::whereHas('users', function ($q) {
    $q->whereNotNull($q->getModel()->getQualifiedDeletedAtColumn());
})->get();
```

It's basically add a where clause to joining table `deleted_at` column which is `not null`. Or this, single line one perhaps works too.

```
User::with('posts')->onlyTrashed()->get()->map->posts->collapse();
```

`onlyTrashed` is a method defined in `SoftDeletes` trait as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#soft-deleting). There exists more 'scope extensions' beside `onlyTrashed`, which are `restore`, `withTrashed`, `withoutTrashed`.

I don't know, but I think adding `->unique('id')` after `collapse` is good, too.

Comment: This is waaaaaay overcomplicating things when OP just needs `User::withTrashed()->whereId($id)->first();`

Comment: @ceejayoz OP question: is there any way to retrieve **posts** that are related to a soft deleted **user**. A relation.

Comment: ok but now whe i try to delete both user and post it just deletes the user and not the post.     public function destroy($id)
    {
        $admins  = User::findOrFail($id);
        $admins  ->delete();
       $admins->project()->delete();
          return redirect()->back();
    }       with this code which is the code used on laracasts. for some reason it doesn't get the post associated to the used but just gets the user and deletes it.this is the error it shows     FatalThrowableError in HomeController.php line 70:
Call to a member function delete() on null

Comment: @Chay22 Once OP has the user, they just do `$user->posts` like normal.

Comment: @ceejayoz As normal as second snippet doesn't it?

Comment: @user3089096 How about reverse the order, I mean, `$admins->project()->delete(); $admins ->delete();`

Comment: still no.somehow $admins->project()->delete() doesn't go through

Comment: Have you tried using event? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20108037/5816907

Comment: still the same.doesn't get the post related