# Delete Data From all tables using Load() Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-blade, destroy

i am trying to delete Model from Model table and all of its comments from Comments table...my current code delete the model but not its comments from the other table...

Here is my destroy function

```
public function destroy(Request $request,CadModel $cadmodel)
    {
        $cadmodel->load('comments')->delete();
        $request->session()->flash('message.level', 'success');
        $request->session()->flash('message.content', 'File Deleted Successfully!');
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
```

Here is the relationship i defined in CadModel Laravel Model...

```
 public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
```

Please Reply and suggest me a solution to delete both..Model and its Comments

Comment: You can use Eloquent. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm

Comment: I need a solution without using Eloquent..

Comment: you will need write your own solution i guess

Comment: why you don't want to use eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

In your migration, set your related comments to be deleted if the model is deleted with `onDelete('cascade')`.

Example:

```
/**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments_model', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('comment_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('model_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('comment_id')->references('id')->on('comments')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('model_id')->references('id')->on('models')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```