# Getting error on one to one function on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, one-to-one, laravel-5.5

I want to join tbl_company_list and tbl_commpany_detail using one to one function on Laravel.

```
@ompany_list table

id (primary_key) | symbol | companyname | sectorid | status

@company_detail table

id (primary_key) | companyid | shares | paidup | baseprice | basepriceRB | operationdate | phone_no | address | website | email | status
```

I want to join 'id' of company_list table to 'companyid' of company_detail table.

I want to make one to one relation such that if I delete companay_list then it will automatically delete commpany_detail. And I also want to get companyname of company_list table from company_detail table.

```
@AdminCompany Model

public static function companydetail(){
    $data = $this->hasOne('App\admin\AdminCompanyDetail');
    return $data; 
}

@AdminCommpanyDetail Model

public static function company(){
    $data = $this->belongsTo('App\admin\AdminCompany');
    return $data; 
}
```

But I am getting error as PHP error:

> Using $this when not in object context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel5.5\app\admin\AdminCompanyDetail.php on line 30

```
@AdminCompany Controller

public function destroy($id)
{
    //
    $company = AdminCompany::findOrFail($id);
    $company->delete();

    return redirect(route('company.index'));
}
```

What code should I need to add to this controller so that I can delete the companydetail also.

Comment: kindly learn the relationship in eloquent from https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships because the way you are using it is not the proper way to use it.

Comment: You can just return it not needed to store it in `$data` variable.

Comment: This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fro AdminCompany  model:

```
public function companydetail()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AdminCompanyDetail::class, 'companyid');
    }
```

And this for the AdminCommpanyDetail

```
 public function company()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AdminCompany:class, 'companyid', 'id' );
    }
```

Comment: And how can I get all the information related rows?

Comment: `$company->companydetail` ?

Comment: I want to get the 'companyname' from the company_detail table and want to show on the view page.

Comment: `$company->companydetail->companyname`