# Laravel 5.4 Delete in cascate

Tags: laravel-5.4

How to perform delete in cascate?
I have two objects, people and contacts.

One people have many contacts, when i delete the people need to delete all contacts, how to do this?

function for delete

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $people= $this->ModelPeople->find($id);

    $people= $people->delete();
}
```

Migration People

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('Peoples', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name',100);
        $table->integer('sex');
        $table->integer('active');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Migration Contact

```
public function up()
{
         Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

         $table->integer('idpeople')->unsigned();
         $table->foreign('idpeople')->references('id')->on('people')->onDelete('cascade');

         $table->string('cel',20)->nullable();
         $table->string('email',100)->nullable();

         $table->timestamps();
     });
 }
```

Model People and Contact

```
    class People Model
    {
        protected $table ='Peoples';
        protected $fillable = ['name','sex','active']; 

        public function Contats(){
            return $this->hasMany(Painel\Contact::class);
        }
    }

    class Contat extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'contacts';
        protected $fillable = ['idpeople','cel','email']; 

        public function people(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Painel\People::class);
        }

    }
```

with this scheme when deleting a person all contacts should be deleted as well? or is this not automatic and I who have to delete the contacts in my destroy method in the controller?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176326/6140684) is an answer that is going to help you. Could you share the migration of your `People` model?

Comment: I used it and it did not work, does it have to do with the version I'm using?

Comment: Have you tried using `php artisan cache:clear` and running the migration again?

Comment: I made the clear and it did not work: / I put the migration

Comment: 1. Try adding `$table->foreign(...)` after `$table->timestamps()`. 2. Any errors on migration? 3. `Fix your typos(s)`