# Can I Associate a Model to the notifications table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have been working on notifications and was getting through it pretty quickly unless I felt the need of deleting and relating a notification to a Post, is there any way I can associate a Model to the `notifications` table?
I thought of using the `$table` property found in the model after creating the notification model.

Edit:
Or can I delete a notification when a post is deleted?

Comment: Is the relationship setup between notification and post?

Comment: No, there's no relation set up between the notification and post. I need Moel to setup the link and that's what I asked. Is there any way to create a model of notifications table

Comment: then how you get notifications from related post ?

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Comment: I store the id of the post. Laravel stores the everything you want in `data` field in the notifications table. I fetch the ID from that field and use for redirection and other purpose

Comment: So would the `data` column in the `notifications` table would hold the `post_id` ?

Comment: yes, `post_id` with some other data such as `post_title` both under `data` field

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course you can.
`php artisan make:model Notification`

Then change the model to extend laravel's default notification model.

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;

    class Notification extends DatabaseNotification
    {
        public function users()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'notifiable_id');
        }
    }
```

Then you can define your relationship in this notification model.

Alternatively, you can delete the notification using user-post relationship

`$post->user->notifications->delete()`

Comment: One and a half year late, but still relevant. Thank you!.

Comment: I would point out that any model can have the Notifiable trait, so while most applications will only use the User for notifications, if another model has the notifiable trait, this could interfere with this function.

Comment: In addition, for the latest version of Larvel (8+), remember to namespace it App\Models.

Comment: @DanS True, in that case, you just need to change the relationship to the model which has the notifiable trait.