# Delete From Multiple Tables Using Cascade

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, cascading-deletes

I have three tables `student`, `user` and `contact,` Student has a relation with Contact and Contact has a relation (`user_id`) with the User table.
When I try to delete from the Student, it should be removed from User and Contact using cascade delete. However, it deletes from the Student table only and keeps data in the User and Contact tables.

**StudentController**

```php
<?php

public function destroy(Student $student)
{
    $student->delete();

    return redirect('/admin/student')->with('success','has been Deleted');
}
```

I  used in student model

```
  public function contact()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Contact');

}

public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($student) {
         $student->contact()->delete();

    });
```

it is worked but I used in contact model

```
  public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

}
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($contact) {
         $contact->user()->delete();

    });
```

in delete student delete contact but not delete user

I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You will have to show us the Schema in order for us to be able to help you. But basically the schema cannot be setup correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically deleting related rows in Laravel (Eloquent ORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Comment: Please add your migrations.

Comment: I build database in phpmyadmin  not use migration