# (Laravel) How to delete multiple models including optional relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

### Summary

I'm trying to let my model controller delete multiple models (selected by an array of IDs) including their ***selected*** related models (selected by an array of relationship names).

### Situation

- Model `Post` with relationships:

  - (One-to-Many) with `Comment` model under `$post->comments()`
  - (One-to-Many) with `Image` model under `$post->images()`
  - (Many-to-One) with `User` model under `$post->user()`
- In `PostController` there's the `destroy_multiple` method that handles the deletion, and where I have:

  - Array `$ids` with IDs of `Post` models to delete (e.g. `[1,2,4]`)
  - Array `$related_models` with relationship names to delete as well (e.g. `['user','comments']` but could be a different selection in each call)

### Attempts

**1) Iterate and delete:**

```
Post::findMany($ids)->each(function($item) use ($related_models) {
    foreach ($related_models as $relation) {
        $item->{$relation}()->delete();
    }
    $item->delete();
});
```

***Problem:*** All models have to be retrieved first, and for each model, all selected related models have to be deleted. This is a LOT of overhead.

**2) Delete related models and models:**

```
// For every selected relationship, delete related models
foreach ($related_models as $relation) {
    $class = 'App\\' . studly_case(str_singular($relation));
    $class::whereIn('post_id', $ids)->delete();
}

// Delete the models
Post::destroy($ids);
```

***Problem:*** This only works for the one-to-many relationships and only provided the database columns are named according to the Laravel standard.

### Question

What is the most efficient way to do this, while:

- using the defined relationships to ensure the right database naming, columns, etc (as in Attempt 1)
- keeping the performance (without having to retrieve the models) (as in Attempt 2)
- keeping the optionality of choosing the `$ids` and `$related_models`

?

### *Notes*

- I know that deleting a parent model (`User` in this case) is not very good practice, but it's there for the sake of the question. ;)
- Using the database `CASCADE` constraint on the foreign keys of the related models' tables (in the migration) makes it lose the optionality. Related models are now *always* deleted, and also in other instances besides the `delete_multiple` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your migration like this:

```
Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->unsignedInteger('posts_id');
    $table->foreign('posts_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('posts')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

The above migration will auto remove every comment related to the post you are deleting.

Comment: True, but then I loose the optionality of choosing which related models to delete at that time. As well as having them deleted in all deletion instances, not just through `delete_multiple`.

Comment: You can apply it to only the related model you want to delete. So when remove a Post, any related models you want to remove with it will have the `onDelete('cascade')` in their migration file. In your case is the User and Comment model, with the given Post's id `[1, 2, 4]` you can do just one line:
`Post::whereIn('id', $arrayOfId)->delete()`

Comment: I know, but I want the user to choose if the related models should be deleted or not (hence the `$related_models` array).

Comment: I do appreciate the suggestion, however :)

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the Relationship models first

Add this method in your Post model:

```
public function delete()
{
    $this->images()->delete();
    $this->comments()->delete();

    return parent::delete(); 
}
```

Call from your controller logic
This will delete the relationship model first and then delete itself

```
Post::findMany($ids)->each(function ($item) {
        $item->delete();
    });
```

Comment: That's Attempt 1, which has a lot of overhead (db and memory). And in your code it always deletes all the related models (not just the ones the user has selected).

Comment: @Philip He ask for the same. He want to delete all ids data which is passed in $ids variable

Comment: All `post` models with IDs in `$ids` and only the related models as provided by `$related_models`. So in some cases none, in other cases one or more of the mentioned relationships based on what the user has selected in the 'confirm delete' modal.

Answer (score 0):

How about declaring the delete method in your model.

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Images::class);
    }

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($post) { 
                $post->comments()->delete();
                $post->images()->delete();
                // or call another method here after you declare above
        });
    }
}
```

So in your controller, call the simple delete function.

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->delete();
```

I use this in my delete relationship function from another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20108037/15909588

Comment: In this solution there is no parameter telling the deleting event which relations to delete as well and which to leave alone. Do you know of a way to forward a custom parameter/argument to the deleting event handler? (So you could do `$model->delete( ['comments'] )`, leaving the `images` alone.)