# Laravel deleting trigger nothing happens

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models with a relationship.

So when Model A will be delete, all related Models B should be also delete.

I'm working with soft deleting.

Here my trigger in Model A:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    // Delete Relations
    self::deleting(function (Customer $customer) {
        $customer->contacts()->delete();
    });
}
```

When I delete a Model A the related Models from B will not be touched. So nothing happens.

So the trigger is not working. I got no error or something else. Has anyone an idea how I should find the mistake?

**Edit:**
The relations looks like this:

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
}
```

and

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
}
```

In all other cases where I use the relation it works fine.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm

Comment: How are you deleting Model A?

Comment: `$customer->delete();`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you need to change your query to complete the relation builder and then delete. Change:

```
$customer->contacts()->delete();
```

to:

```
$customer->contacts->delete();
```

Comment: Thank you. I'v changed my code but it's still the same problem :(

Comment: Can you post you model relationship please.

Comment: Have you tried `static::deleting` instead of `self::deleting`?

Comment: @Markus Have you tried `static::deleted` instead of `static::deleting`?

Comment: No matter if I use deleted or deleting. Same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your migration file

```
$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');
```

you can also delete the contacts before delete the customer like this

```
class Customer extends Eloquent
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Contact');
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        // delete all related contacts
        $this->contacts()->delete();

        // delete the customer
        return parent::delete();
    }
}
```