# How do you destroy 2 rows, one of each table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have 2 tables `users` and `user_info` where the `users` id is used in the `user_info` user_id column. In order to destroy the one in the `users`, I used this command in Controller

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$user->delete();
```

I also had to remove the one from the `user_info`

```
$userInfo = UserInfo::findOrFail($id);
$userInfo->delete();
```

But I can't think of the right logic to delete the column that has the user's `id` and the user_info's `user_id`

Comment: Do you have relationship in both models?

Comment: Please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically deleting related rows in Laravel (Eloquent ORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Comment: Using an event listener/observer is the way to go if you will always be deleting the `users` record via the Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$userInfo = UserInfo::where('user_id', $id)->first()->delete();
```

Or if you have defined your relation `userInfo()` in User Model you can use (**before deleting the user**)

```
$user->userInfo->delete()
```

Comment: I think all answers are correct but I would like to mark this as the answer because it's easy to understand for my level

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user=User::find($id);
$user_info=UserInfo::where('user_id',$id)->first();

$user->delete();
$user_info->delete();
```

you use first() it returns a single model, not a collection as like using find() with id where id need be primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `Soft Deletes`, then I suggest using cascade in your migration.

```
//secondary table
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

else, you can use the relationship to delete both records using the following logic:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
//assuming info is defined in the user model
$user->info->delete();
//now you can delete the user
$user->delete();
```