# cascade user deletion laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to delete a user but there is `ForeignKey` constraints that I also need to delete.

In my User model, I have

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'email', 
        'password',
        'timezone', 
        'profile_picture', 
        'notification_key'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 
        'pivot', 
        'admin'
    ];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($instance) {
            $instance->id = Uuid::uuid4();
        });
    }

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class)
                    ->withPivot('user_role')
                    ->withTimestamps();        
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class);
    }

}
```

migrations for relation are

```
class CreateEventUserTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('event_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('event_id');
            $table->uuid('user_id');
            $table->primary(['event_id', 'user_id']);

            $table->foreign('event_id')->references('id')->on('events');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('event_user');
    }
}
```

and

```
class CreateGroupUserTable extends Migration
{

    {
        Schema::create('group_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('group_id');
            $table->uuid('user_id');
            $table->string('user_role')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->boolean('owner');
            $table->primary(['group_id', 'user_id']);

            $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('group_user');
    }
}
```

so I was trying to delete user like this

```
public function delete($user) 
{
    $user = User::findOrfail('id', $user->id);
    $res = $user->groups()->events()->delete();

    if ($res) {
        return response('Success, user was deleted', 204);
    } else {
        return response()->json(error);
    }
}
```

but still, I'm receiving

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`event_activities`, CONSTRAINT `event_activities_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `users` where `id` = someID) in file /home/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 664
```

I was hoping to do deletion in the manner by relationship in the User model, but I'm still receiving an Integrity error, so what is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Can you show your migrations?

Comment: ok @senty I have added relation migration

Comment: You missed `->onDelete('cascade');` on your migrations, that might be it?

Comment: @senty, not my cup of tea, I'm trying to understand what they did before me, but thanks for the clarification, I'll play, I have accepted you're answer

Comment: I'd be happy to clarify, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to achieve this:

- Using detach

  ```
  $user->groups()->events()->detach();
  $user->groups()->detach();
  ```
- Utilise the deleting event on related models like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20108037/4705339)
- Migrations.

  ```
  // in user_roles

  $table->integer('group_id');
  $table->foreign('group_id')->references("id")->on("groups")->onDelete("cascade");
  ```

  This translates into:
      When group 'id' is deleted on 'groups', delete this row.

  Apply same thing to groups for events.

**Edit:**

Looking at your migrations, you implemented 3rd solution, but you seem to forget

`->onDelete('cascade');`