# CRUDE operations Using Eloquent Model having relationship between tables

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, postman, eloquent-relationship

I have these tables: [ERD of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvZeQ.jpg)

I'm making an API and I've built relationships among theses tables:

1.

```
class address extends Model
{
    public $timestamps=false;
    protected $guarded=[];
    protected $primaryKey = 'addressID';
    protected $fillable = ['streetAddress','country','city','postalCode','employeeID'];



    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(employee::class);
    }

}
```

2.

```
class department extends Model
{
    public $timestamps=false;

    protected $primaryKey = 'departmentID';
    protected $fillable= ['departmentName'];

    public  function role()
    {
    return $this->hasMany(role::class);
    }
    public  function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(employee::class);
    }
```

3.

```
class employee extends Model
{

    public $timestamps=false;
  //  protected $guarded=[];
    protected $primaryKey = 'employeeID';
    protected $fillable = ['firstName','lastName','email','password','phone','gender','roleID','departmentID'];


    public  function address()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(address::class);
    }


    public  function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(department::class);
    }

    public  function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(role::class);
    }


}
```

4.

```
class privilege extends Model
{
    public $timestamps=false;
    protected $guarded=[];
    protected $primaryKey = 'privilegeID';
    protected $fillable = ['privilageName','roleID'];



    public  function statuse()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(statuse::class);
    }
    public  function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(role::class);
    }
}
```

5.

```
class role extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $primaryKey = 'roleID';
    protected $fillable = ['roleName','departmentID'];

    public  function privilege()
    {
    return $this->hasMany(privilege::class);
    }

    public  function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(employee::class);
    }
    public  function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(department::class);
    }



}
```

6.

```
class statuse extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $primaryKey = 'statusID';
    protected $fillable = ['edit', 'delete', 'view','privilegeID'];

    public function privilege()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(privilege::class);
    }

}
```

Now my *role* and *employee* tables are dependent on *department* table so I want that when I delete any *department*, it's related *employees* and *roles* should also be deleted.
I don't know how to do it using eloquent model.

I've tried this in my **role Controller** but it's not working.

```
  public function destroy($id)
    {

        $roles = new role;
        $roles = $roles::find($id);
        $roles->$roles->departments()->attach(['departmentID']))->delete();
        //$roles->delete($roles->departments()->attach(['departmentID']));
        if ($roles) {
            $finaldata['status'] = "Record Deleted";
            $finaldata['reason'] = "Record Deleted Successfully";

        } else {

            $finaldata['status'] = "Record Not Deleted";
            $finaldata['reason'] = "Record was not present";

        }
        $finaldata['deleted role data '] = $roles;
        return response()->json($finaldata);

    }

}
```

May be I'm missing any point or logic here, kindly guide me.

Comment: In your department migration you need to declare the foreign entries to cascade delete https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176326/972235