# Deleting eloquent relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relation, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables, `Order`, `OrderItem` and `GoldSilver`. `OrderItem` has an `order_id` from `Order` table and `OrderItem` has `gold_silver_id`.
So, Upon deleting `Order` I want to delete related `OrderItem` and `GoldSilver`. I can delete OrderItem through Laravel Eloquent relationship, but how can I delete GoldSilver too.
Here is my model:
Order.php

```
public function orderItem()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
}
```

OrderItem.php

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}

public function goldSilver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(GoldSilver::class);
}
```

GoldSilver.php

```
public function orderItem()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OrderItem::class);
}
```

In my controller for delete I am doing:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
   
    $order =  Order::find($id);
    $order->orderItem;
 
    $dltorder = $order->orderItem()->delete();

    if($dltorder){
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>'Success',
            'message'=>'Order deleted'
        ],200);
    }
}
```

How can I do so? Helpis appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: create a new migration and define foreign key constraints in it and you won't need to do extra code for deleting items from other tables.

Comment: I do not want to use cascade on delete @NaveedAli

Comment: you have to loop through the orderItem relation

Comment: easy way: you have $order , then $order_item = $order->orderItem; then  loof on order ites and delete$order_item->goldSilver()->delete(); then delete orderItem $order->orderItem()->delete;

Comment: you need to add static function boot as here
[check this ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Comment: I would recommend using cascades, Its the most logical solution. However, you can try: ```$order->orderItem->goldSilver()->delete()``` or ```$orderItem = OrderItem::findOrFail($order->orderItem->id); $orderItem->goldSilver()->delete();```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like below in destroy method:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
   //you have $order id, find the order and then the relation with orderItems
    $order =  Order::find($id);
    foreach($order->orderItem as $orderItem){
       $orderItem->goldSilver()->delete();
    }
 
    $dltorder = $order->orderItem()->delete();

    if($dltorder){
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>'Success',
            'message'=>'Order deleted'
        ],200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the `goldSiver` relation be deleted anytime an order item is deleted you can set up an [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers) for the order item and perform it in the deleting method. This prevents you from having to perform the extra deletion in your controller and ensures the `goldSilver` relationship will always be deleted when an order item is deleted without having to repeat yourself.

```
public function deleting(OrderItem $orderItem){
    $orderItem->goldSilver()->delete();
 }
```