# Laravel Deep Nested relation delete query

Tags: php, laravel

i have 4 models which are related with each other..
1st Model:
school:

```
 
     public function contactpersons()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ContactPerson::class, 'school_id', 'id');
    }
```

2nd Model:
ContactPerson:

```
  public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Address::class, 'address_contact_person', 'contact_person_id', 'address_id');
    }
```

3rd Model:
Address:

```
 public function contactPersonAddresses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ContactPerson::class, 'address_contact_person', 'address_id', 'contact_person_id');
    }
```

4th model: pivot table

```
AddressContactPerson:
```

Now the question is ..
i want my records of Address and AddressContactPerson to be deleted when i delete the contact person . i tried with firing delete events but couldnt make it. the events were not triggerd ..
i have to delete these records from School Model..
$school->contactpersons()->delete();
and i have softDeletes on every Models.
this will only delete contactpersons record not the 'Address' and AddressContactPerson table..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically deleting related rows in Laravel (Eloquent ORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Comment: no it didnt .. i did look at it but it didnt help me .. when i delete the school it deletes the contactperson but wont further delete the address and addresscontactperson table... thats what i am looking for .. couldnt find a way .

Comment: Can you show more of your code. In which model you have made what relationships?

Answer (score 0):

In your Schema you should have a foreign key and then set  onDelete('cascade').
Something like this:

```
$table->biginteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: how am i supposed to assign foreign key on contactperson model when it doesnt have any id related with address table ?

Comment: In your model you should have a delete() function in which you call the delete() function on your relationship. E.g if you have a user model and when you delete a user you want to delete all the relationship associated, you should try something like that:`public function delete()
    {
        DB::transaction(function()
        {
            $this->yourRelationship()->delete();
            parent::delete();
        });`